# How can I rename the column table name inside of the SubSonic Scaffolding control?

Tags: subsonic, scaffolding, scaffold

I would like that someone explain me how is the easy and simple way to change the HeaderText of the GridView control using the SubSonic Scaffolding ? Also, I would like to rename the text of every label control in the Add and Edit Form that is generated with the SubSonic Scaffold.

I got my Scaffolding Form in English idiom but I want to translate into Spanish idiom.

I use SubSonic version 2.1 (Final)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is use the [subsonic scaffold gen](http://dl.activeaspsoftware.net/dl.aspx?f=SubSonicScaffoldGen.zip) to generate instead of the default scaffolding. It allows you to generate once then customize the fields, etc. But you have to re-generate once you change the database model.